# How to open Pdf in android 11 from scoped storage

Tags: android, kotlin, android-11

I have a question about file permissions in **android 11**. I am trying to open a PDF file in PDF viewer from my application but I am unable to do that because of the change in permissions in android 11. Can someone please give me a code snippet of how to do that since I am unable to find any code regarding this issue.

I am saving the pdf file in
`context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir`

I have tried to open the pdf file via

```
        val pdfFile = File(filePath)
        pdfIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(pdfFile), "application/pdf")
        pdfIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY

        pdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        pdfIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
        context.startActivity(pdfIntent)
```

this code is running on devices below android 11 but not working on android 11.

```
        val pdfIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply { 
                         addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE) 
                        }
        val pdfFile = File(filePath)
        pdfIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(pdfFile), "application/pdf")
        pdfIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY

        pdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        pdfIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
        context.startActivity(pdfIntent)
```

I found this code in searching of scope storage but nothing happened

Comment: "I am saving the pdf file in context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir" -- that is not a particularly good location. Use `getFilesDir()` on `Context` instead. "this code is running on devices below android 11" -- that code should be crashing with a `FileUriExposedException`. If you save the PDF in `getFilesDir()`, you can [use `FileProvider` and its `getUriForFile()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider). See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing) for more.

Answer (score 0):

In android 11 do not allow applications to see files of other applications. To share files you need to use a content provider. How to declare and setup are available in the content provider tutorials